# Themeable browser use UIWebView forcefully with ionic capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am doing ionic application with capacitor.

I have to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser plugin for one funcationality but when I make build and upload to apple store app is rejected because of UiWebView issue.

Commands for installing themeable plugin

```
npm install cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser
npm install @ionic-native/themeable-browser
ionic cap sync
```

If I remove that plugin and upload it to apple build process pass successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Apple no longer accepts new submissions using UIWebView: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122114

There is also an Ionic blog article: https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

You can use [Capacitor's Browser API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/browser), but it is quite limited compared to some existing Cordova plugins. However it is built around WKWebView and is therefore compliant.

There is AFAIK no alternative but to move to WKWebView if you want your app to be on the Apple App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Themeable Browser instead of InAppBrowser because you need to customize the toolbar and other components. Unfortunately Themeable Browser is no longer a supported project. In InAppBrowser version 5.0.0 https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/02/16/inappbrowser-release-5.0.0.html only uses WKWebView and you can now set InAppBrowserStatusBarStyle to "darkcontent". Unfortunately, other changes have to be applied manually. I succeeded for Android and I fight for Ios :-)